# spark-submit to cloudera cluster can not find any dependent jars

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera

I am able to do a spark-submit to my cloudera cluster. the job dies after a few minutes with exceptions complaining it can not find various classes. These are classes that are in the spark dependency path. I keep adding the jars one at a time using command line args --jars, the yarn log keeps dumping out the next jar it can't find.

What setting allows the spark/yarn job to find all the dependent jars?

I already set the "spark.home" attribute to the correct path - /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark

Comment: Clarify what classes you are talking about? Spark classes or your own? How are you running spark-submit?

Comment: these are spark classes. I am using spark-submit specifying yarn cluster as the master. It appears to be a cluster configuration problem. The node which complains about classnotfound is always node 2, even when I decommission it from spark. Why would yarn contact node 2 for a spark job, if that node is no longer part of the spark cluster?

Comment: here is the partail spark-submit script - #!/bin/bash
export SPARK_HOME=/home/bruce/workspace1/spark-cloudera
source $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh
/home/bruce/workspace1/spark-cloudera/bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--master yarn \
--verbose \
 /home/bruce/workspace1/spark-cloudera/examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples-1.0.0-cdh5.1.0-hadoop2.3.0-cdh5.1.0.jar 10. left out the --driver-class-path line which is too long.

Comment: this is not tied to node 2. after removing node 2 altogether, node 1 is displaying the same exceptions. Some how, yarn application master does not see the spark dependency classes. Any body know how that dependency is set up?

Comment: I cheated by adding assembly.jar to --jar. now I move past the class dependencies. However, this is obviously not the proper way. I checked that this assembly.jar is also at hdfs /user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly.jar. but application master just can't see it. Any ideas?

Comment: Dunno, it works out of the box. Nothing needs to be set. I think it's a question of what you may have changed in the config? did you try to overwrite with your own installation?

Comment: no, I have made that mistakes too many times to repeat it. And I re-installed a number of times to make sure everything is back to default. When you say out of the box, you did set up spark-env.sh and spark-default.conf and all that, right?

Comment: No. You don't have to configure anything. I think you are doing something quite different like manually changing config or overwriting Spark with something.

Comment: I am talking about on the client side. I am quite certain you will have to set up these config files, or else the submitting client would have no idea where to send. see http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_running_spark_apps.html and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: IIRC spark-defaults.conf is set up for you already so you can send jobs with just spark-submit on the cluster. Off the cluster, use --master to specify the master. That's about all that's essential. Your error doesn't seem to be in submitting but in the jar you are submitting

Comment: don't think we are talking about the same set up. You do know that there are 3 modes for submission: standalone, yarn client and yarn cluster. when you specify --master to be yarn, spark-submit needs to look up how to contact yarn. That's the reason, I think, you need to set up spark-default.conf on the client side. The instruction is very clear about that. http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_running_spark_apps.html. I am wondering, have you successfully done spark-submit from off the cluster yet?

Comment: Yes, I am a Spark contributor and work at Cloudera. I think I'm not understanding your setup and therefore not helping, but it's not for lack of understanding Spark.

Comment: I see. Excuse my inquiry. My set up is off cluster submission, where you declare yarn as the master. in that case, the submission script obviously must figure out where to find yarn server. I have yarn-site.xml on the client side (downloaded from the cluster). My understanding is spark-default.xml needs to be set up as well on the client. you seem to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

remove

.set("spark.driver.host", "driver computer ip address")

from your driver code.