# spark-submit: application master can not talk back to driver

Tags: cloudera, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I submitted a spark job to Cloudera cluster using spark-submit in YARN cluster mode.

I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:187)
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /myip:0
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272).
```

Any one knows why application master can not bind to the driver IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

remove

.set("spark.driver.host", "driver computer ip address")

from your driver code.

also posted on 
[spark-submit to cloudera cluster can not find any dependent jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495661/spark-submit-to-cloudera-cluster-can-not-find-any-dependent-jars)